# How to get all ID from a class (iFrame) on the attached photo?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

[image]

Maybe we can use var everyChild = document.querySelectorAll(**XXX**)

Comment: I think you should try to solve the problem first, when you get stuck on something then we can help

Comment: I've been trying for days.

Comment: Where's the proof of trying?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const elements = document.querySelector('.photos_choose_rows').querySelectorAll('div > a')
const ids = Array.from(elements).map(el=> el.id);
```

Comment: I don't see on your screen if div marked as green has three classes ("photos", "chose", "rows") or one class ("photos_choose_rows"). If it's one class then change document.querySelector('.photos') into document.querySelector('.photos_choose_rows')

Comment: '. Photos_choose_rows' is not a valid selector.

Comment: i added the second photo with the class information

Comment: <div id="photos_choose_rows469284696_252773047" class="photos_choose_rows">

Comment: If this document has the same structure like your picture presents then it should work. I tested it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQdJQB?editors=1111 and ids are printed to the console.

Comment: A good answer should contain an explanation as to why this solves the specific problem posted by the asker. Even if you are answering a low-quality question with images rather than text, your solution could/should be helpful for other users as well.